# download button for audio file in post

Tags: plugins, posts, uploads, media-library, audio

I am setting up a website for audio files, i have uploaded an audio file and inserted in a post in given link http://darsequranmardan.com/quran/siparah-18/1-surah-al-mumenoon-ayat-1-to-16/ the audio file inserted in this post is streamable but i also want to give a download button for the users so they can download the audio file. I inserted the button and then linked it with the audio file but when user hit the download the button the audio file starts to open instead of downloading. Is there something forcing the file not to download?
i have seen the other website which is doing the same but there audio file is downloadable and mine is not here is the link http://www.tasawwuf.co/namaz-ke-asrar-o-ramooz-%D9%86%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B2-%DA%A9%DB%92-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D9%88-%D8%B1%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<a href="http://darsequranmardan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/4%20Al-Rad%20Ayat-1%20Part-2.mp3" download="4%20Al-Rad%20Ayat-1%20Part-2.mp3">download</a>
```

The structure is:

```
<a href="http://test.com/uploads/path/file.mp3" download="file.mp3">download</a>
```

[Here is a great article on the `download` attribute.](https://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute)

Comment: You beat me to it +1.

Comment: But note that this link attribute doesn't seems to be supported by kses. So you have to be an admin to be able to add it in the editor, else it get's removed.

Comment: thank you sir it really worked, i also found out that only adding download attribute will also work.

Comment: @AbuBakar You might want the filename in the attribute for better compatibility.